# C# - How to cancel background working from form with a progress bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm trying to figure out how I can cancel a backgroundwoker with the following situation:

On one Winform, I have a backgroundworker that I call that basically retrieves a ton of data from a service. This operation can take anywhere from 1 second to 5 minutes. So, what I did was I created another Winform and stuck a marquee progress bar on it.

What I'm wanting to do is to add a Cancel button to that Winform with the progress bar on it that would cancel that backgroundworker.

My current code is setup as:

```
this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
pb = new frmProgressbar();
pb.Show();

while (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
{
   Application.DoEvents();
}

pb.Dispose();
```

So, this works fine as it displays the progressbar while the backgroundworker is chugging along, and disposes of the progressbar form afterwards.

But, I need to figure out a way to allow the user to cancel the operation by placing a Cancel button on frmProgressbar that will return a cancel to kill the backgroundworker. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, please, *please* don't use `DoEvents`, unless you're *really* sure that you know what you're doing.  It's almost always the wrong tool for the job.  There's no point in creating another thread to do work if you're just going to have the main thread sitting there waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Add a public event to the progress form class, fire it with the button's Click event handler.  Subscribe that event in your snippet, have it call the BGW's CancelAsync() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start out by adding an event to the progress bar form to indicate when cancellation occurs and then fire it when the relevant button is clicked:

```
public class frmProgressbar : Form
{
    public event Action Canceled;

    void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Canceled != null)
            Canceled();
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

Then in your other form you can create a new progress bar, have it cancel the background worker (which has its own cancellation support built in) and then show it.  You can also add a handler to the completed event to close the progress bar (rather than trying to wait on the BGW).  Then start the worker.

You'll also need to check for cancellation from throughout your `DoWork` handler so that you can stop doing your work in the event that cancellation is requested:

```
var pb = new frmProgressbar();
pb.Canceled += ()=> backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
pb.Show();

backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) => pb.Close();
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: I feel dumb. How do I check for cancellation in the DoWork handler? I have made the changes to reflect your suggestion above, but not sure how to check for cancellation.

Comment: @user1949119 `backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending` or the `Cancel` property of the event arguments for `DoWork`.

Comment: I'm really sorry for being ignorant on this. In my backgroundWorker1_DoWork event, I am calling a method that grabs the data. I still don't get how to cancel it inside of that event.

Comment: @user1949119 If you don't have any way of stopping it, or of altering it to have it support cancellation than what do you expect it to do?  If it doesn't support cancellation then it doesn't support cancellation.  The most you can do when a use hits "cancel" is close the progress bar and let them do other stuff again (so long as that other stuff will work with that operation being still in progress).

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice on this. I know it's probably frustrating dealing with people who aren't familiar with things like this. I was under the assumption that there was a "simple" method for just canceling the backgroundworker since it was running in a separate thread from the calling thread. Following your code as an example (which I am certainly appreciative of), I set it up with the public event on the progressbar form, and modified how it's calling the backgroundworker. The method in the background worker is basically a datatable that is populated from a call to a service.

Comment: @user1949119 No, there is no magic way to cancel it if it doesn't support cancellation.  If you have control over the source though you can pass in the event args and have it periodically check to see if it is cancelled if it's in a position to gracefully stop at that point.